# How to translate the "Information" section of the page layout?

Tags: translation, translation-workbench

Each custom object has its "Information" section on the page layout:

[image]

I wanted to translate it in Translation Workbench, but it's not visible there:

[image]

Is there any other place where I could translate this section, or it's not possible?

I tried to overcome this via the XLIFF translation file, but adding the section manually together with changing the order of other items by '1' didn't work, and I received errors when importing the translation:

> Invalid key LayoutSection.InvoiceRequest__c.Invoice Request Layout.Information_1: Some keys are appended with their sort order for uniqueness. Re-export your file and ensure that the keys in both files match.

Comment: You can translate custom section header only

Comment: @elijah Hi, thanks for the info. Is there any SF documentation that could confirm this?

Comment: I couldnt find it but we faced similar issue and resolved it by removing standard section header from layout (marking not visible ) and creating custom section header. Let me know if this resolves your isuse. (Standard labels will get translated automatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant give custom translation for standard section headers as they are translated automatically.

If you want to have custom translation you should make standard section header invisible
By simply unchecking both detail and edit page options and create new section header with same name
[image]

I found same information in metadata api document for layouts

[image]
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_layouts.htm